# Exception when compiling with ant

Tags: java, macos, ant, compilation, version

I hope no-one has asked this before (I couldn't find anything, but that may just be poor searching).  I am compiling by running ant in my root directory.  However, I get this error:

```
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
```

I know this is because it wants Java 1.6, and is using 1.5, but my mac has Java 1.6 as well (I've checked in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions).  How can I get ant to run with 1.6 so that I can compile?

EDIT:
I've added the correct path of Java 1.6 to /etc/profile, and 
`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`, after this line.  Executing java -version gives the correct version (1.6.0), but running ant -v still produces the same error, and states that Java 1.5 is being used.

Does anyone know how I can force ant to use Java 1.6?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the jdk you want to use.

There're many ways to do that. E.g., if you're on mac/linux, you could add this to `/etc/profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java
```

On windows, IIRC, there's a menu in My Computer/properties.

Comment: I can't find my profile file.  should it be in my home directory?

Comment: @tiswas Create it, then. It's `/etc/profile` file, nothing to do with home directory. Each time you start bash session in terminal, it'll be executed. (There're other places where you can put it too, you can google if you want to have it in home directory)

Comment: I've created the profile file in /etc with the line:
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home
but I still get the same problem when running ant..

Comment: @tiswas You have to start new ssh session (e.g., open new terminal tab) for changes to take effect. Then, you can execute `echo $JAVA_HOME` and see if it's there. For me it produces `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home`.

Comment: I think I've found my problem.  There is already a profile file in /etc.  I'm trying to edit this (inserting my line for the JAVA_HOME), but I can't save as it's read only.  I've tried in both TextEdit and vi..

Comment: @tiswas Try `sudo vi`. You can also change file permissions, if you're not concerned about exposing it: `sudo chmod 777 /etc/profile`.

Comment: ARG!  I've managed to edit it now, and when I execute echo $JAVA_HOME I het the right response, but I'm STILL getting the same error when I run ant.  What is going on?!  Sorry for all these questions, and thanks for your help!

Comment: thank you - I have made sure to reopen terminal since making the changes.  I have no idea I'm afraid how to edit the ant script - I'm just trying to compile I project I have just downloaded..

Comment: @tiswas You might need to change `PATH` variable: `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` (after you've set `$JAVA_HOME`). I'm not sure if ant uses it, but it won't hurt to try. To verify, execute `java -version` in console and see the response.

Comment: Sorry, I did it a long time ago, so I don't remember all the tricks.

Comment: yup - now getting the correct response (java version "1.6.0_22), but error still going on..  Maybe I've misinterpretted the meaning of 'class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0'..

Comment: @tiswas Try executing your ant command with verbose flag, like `ant -v build`. It'll print path to java in the first lines.

Comment: yup - here's what I get when I run ant -v:   
Detected Java version: 1.5 in: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home

Comment: [According to the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars), it should work. Sorry, I'm out of ideas now. You might want to check that page, just in case it contains something useful.